# Special plain header gets deleted by editing font size in doc

Tags: header-footer, fontsize, fancyhdr

After reading on this website, I have created a header on the first page that is different from the rest of the pages headers writing this in the preamble:

```
\documentclass[twoside,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{lipsum} % Lorem ipsum

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} % Use 8-bit encoding that has 256 glyphs
\usepackage{setspace} % Line spacing
\usepackage{microtype} % Slightly tweak font spacing for aesthetics
\usepackage[hmarginratio=1:1,top=32mm,columnsep=20pt,headheight=48pt]{geometry} % Document margins
\usepackage{multicol} % Used for the two-column layout of the document
\usepackage{tgschola}

\usepackage[hang, small,labelfont=bf,up,textfont=it,up]{caption} % Custom captions under/above floats in tables or figures
\usepackage{booktabs} % Horizontal rules in tables
\usepackage{float} % Required for tables and figures in the multi-column environment - they need to be placed in specific locations with the [H] (e.g. \begin{table}[H])
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{dblfloatfix}
\usepackage{flafter}

\usepackage{natbib} %Loader bibtex
\usepackage{bibentry}
\usepackage{hyperref} % For hyperlinks in the PDF

\usepackage{lettrine} % The lettrine is the first enlarged letter at the beginning of the text
\usepackage{paralist} % Used for the compactitem environment which makes bullet points with less space between them

\usepackage{titlesec} % Allows customization of titles
\renewcommand\thesection{\Roman{section}} % Roman numerals for the sections
\renewcommand\thesubsection{\Roman{subsection}} % Roman numerals for subsections
\titleformat{\section}[block]{\normalsize\itshape\bfseries\centering}{\thesection.}{1em}{} % Change the look of the section titles
\titleformat{\subsection}[block]{\itshape\bfseries\centering\small}{\thesubsection.}{1em}{} % Change the look of the section titles
\titlespacing{\section}{0pt}{8pt}{0pt}
\titlespacing{\subsection}{0pt}{0pt}{0pt}
\usepackage{fancyhdr} % Headers and footers
\pagestyle{fancy} % All pages have headers and footers
\usepackage{lastpage}
\fancyhead{} % Blank out the default header
\fancyfoot{} % Blank out the default footer

\widowpenalty10000
\clubpenalty10000

\usepackage{titling}
\pretitle{\begin{flushleft}}
\posttitle{\par\end{flushleft}\vskip 0.5em}
\preauthor{\begin{flushleft}}
\postauthor{\par\end{flushleft}}
\predate{\begin{flushleft}\vskip -3em}
\postdate{\par\end{flushleft}}

%-------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   HEADER
%-------------------------------------------------------------------------

\fancypagestyle{plain}{%
  \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}%
  \fancyhf{}%
  \lhead{\Large\textbf{\textit{Header on front page}}}
  \rhead{\tiny \textsc{Header} \\
  Subject, \today}
  \fancyfoot[C]{Page \thepage\ of \pageref{LastPage}}%
}

\fancyhead[C]{Header on other pages} % Custom header text
\fancyfoot[C]{Page \thepage\ of \pageref{LastPage}} % Custom footer text
```

And this in my document:

```
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% Journal Article
% LaTeX Template
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   PACKAGES AND OTHER DOCUMENT CONFIGURATIONS
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
\input{preamble}
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   TITLE SECTION
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\title{\vspace{-15mm}\fontsize{14pt}{0pt}\selectfont\textbf{Title}\vspace{-3mm}} % Article title

\author{
\small
\hspace{4em}\textbf{Authors}\\ % Your name
\hspace{4em}\small Place, \today
\vspace{1mm}}

\date{}

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\begin{document}

\maketitle % Insert title
\thispagestyle{plain}

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   Summary
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\noindent\makebox[\textwidth][c]{%
    \begin{minipage}{1\textwidth}

\begin{spacing}{1.0}
\small\textbf{Abstract:} \textit{Max 200 words.}
\end{spacing}
    \end{minipage}}

\vspace*{5mm}

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   ARTICLE CONTENTS
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\begin{multicols}{2} % Two-column layout throughout the main article text

\section{Introduction}
\vspace*{-10pt}

\lipsum
\cite{Gubbay1990}

\thispagestyle{fancy} % All pages have headers and footers   

\lipsum

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   REFERENCE LIST
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
\bibliographystyle{unsrt}
\nobibliography{bib.bib} %brug \nobibliography{bib.bib} hvis referencer ikke skal vises - til eksempelvis wordcount.


%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\end{multicols}

\end{document}
```

The special header I have created by altering the `plain` header gets overwritten with the `fancy` header, which is supposed to be only on the other pages not the front page.

If I write `\small` or anything like that to change the font size in the document, the header gets deleted as well.

Comment: Welcome! Please make your code into a compilable example which we can copy-paste-compile to reproduce the problem. That's much more helpful to both us and you than some fragments of code, which may or may not include the problem.

Comment: Oh, thanks! I have tried to make a compilable example, but I had some difficulties sorting out the codes as I am very new to LaTex. So I guess there is a bit more code in my example than you are used to in here. Hope that you want to help me out anyways...

Comment: Thanks. Do please take a look at [this question on meta](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that?s=3|0.6331). It explains a bit about how to create a minimal example and should be helpful, especially if you are new to LaTeX. (Note that the same process is useful for diagnosing problems yourself. Indeed, it is really the troubleshooting method after reading errors, which don't always help anyways.)

Comment: Off-topic: you are loading packages willy-nilly which is a common beginner's error. You almost certainly have too many. (Do you know what they all do?) They are definitely in the wrong order. At least `hyperref` should be loaded last save for a few exceptions. If you don't know it is an exception, put it first to begin with.

Comment: Also, don't use explicit markup in the arguments to commands like `\title{}` etc. Change what `\maketitle` does instead (as you do with `titling`).

Comment: Your example compiles as expected for me. I just merged the preamble into the document and commented out the bibliography stuff as I don't have `bib.bib` and I get a different header on the first page than the others.  Whether I use 10pt or 12pt makes no difference except to the size.

Comment: Oh, I found the mistake! I put the:

    \thispagestyle{fancy} 

too early in the text, so it appeared on the front page... Sorry!

Comment: Please take a look at the meta question I linked - a minimal example needs to demonstrate the problem ;).

Comment: By the way, that template was updated a few weeks ago. Maybe the new version is better.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because there is no problem at all and the OP find the mistake.